# Flash fallback for javascript "ended" event listener?

Tags: javascript, flash, html5-video, fallback

I'm using this script to load a series of videos that a user has selected on a form on a previous page... it loads a video array using the `<video>` tag, and I was wondering what the best way to provide a flash-based fallback would be — is it simply a matter of browser detection and loading a completely flash-based alternative to the script, or is there an easier way to modify the existing script?

```
function getUrlVars() {
    var vars = {};
    var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function(m,key,value) {
        vars[key] = value;
    });
    return vars;
}


   function myEndedListener(){
      var myVideo = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];
      myVideo.addEventListener('ended',myNewSrc,false);
   }

   var position = 0;
   var videoList=new Array('one.mp4', 'two.mp4', 'three.mp4');

   function myNewSrc() {
      var myVideo = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];
      if(++position >= videoList.length) {
         position = 0;
      }
      myVideo.src=videoList[position];
      myVideo.load();
      myVideo.play();
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using Event.COMPLETE event ........ `myVideo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,myNewSrc,false);`